# Linkedin user id length

Tags: mysql, linkedin-api

I create a LinkedIn App and using thier API.
I need to store Linkedin user ID in Mysql and I dont know what length of field I shoud take.
**What is length of field of user ID?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit whatsoever specified in the documentation. So for safety you can set 64 (or 128) varchar.